# For loop optimization to create an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, graph, pytorch

I am currently working with graph with labeled edges.
The original adjacency matrix is a matrix with shape [n_nodes, n_nodes, n_edges] where each cell [i,j, k] is 1 if node i and j are connected via edge k.

I need to create a reverse of the original graph, where nodes become edges and edges become nodes, so i need a new matrix with shape [n_edges, n_edges, n_nodes], where each cell [i,j,k] is 1 if edges i and j have k as a common vertex.

[image]

The following code correctly completes the task, but the use of 5 nested for-loops is too slow, to process the amount of graphs with which I have to work seems to take about 700 hours.

Is there a better way to implement this?

```
n_nodes = extended_adj.shape[0]
n_edges = extended_adj.shape[2]
reversed_graph = torch.zeros(n_edges, n_edges, n_nodes, 1)
for i in range(n_nodes):
    for j in range(n_nodes):
        for k in range(n_edges):
            #If adj_mat[i][j][k] == 1 nodes i and j are connected with edge k
            #For this reason the edge k must be connected via node j to every outcoming edge of j
            if extended_adj[i][j][k] == 1:
                #Given node j, we need to loop through every other possible node (l)
                for l in range(n_nodes):
                    #For every other node, we need to check if they are connected by an edge (m)
                    for m in range(n_edges):
                        if extended_adj[j][l][m] == 1:
                            reversed_graph[k][m][j] = 1
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Myabe this could help: "The edge-adjacency matrix of a graph G is identical to the vertex-adjacency matrix of the line graph L(G) of G"

Comment: Pheh, only now I understood your previous (deleted) question. You could get better feedback there, if said, that tensor in question is for graphs representation.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov the deleted question was intended to merge graphs, and I solved it, this is another problem.

Comment: Yes, I got it. You deleted your question in vain, it would be better if you supplemented the information and provided a solution.

Comment: As for new one, [n_edges, n_edges, **n_nodes**] is rather be [n_edges, n_edges, **new_edges**] isn't it?

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov each pair of edges can have in common one of the original nodes, and i need to keep track of which one is connecting them, so new_edges is equal to n_nodes

Comment: This graph representation is horribly inefficient. Why don't you use a square matrix where the entries are the edge number ? (And a reserved value for "not edge")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing the comments above, this graph representation is almost certainly cumbersome and inefficient. But that notwithstanding, let's define a  vectorized solution without loops and that uses tensor views whenever possible, which should be fairly efficient to compute for larger graphs.

For clarity let's use `[i,j,k]` to index `G` (original graph) and `[i',j',k']` to index `G'` (new graph). And let's shorten `n_edges` to `e` and `n_nodes` to `n`.

Consider the 2D matrix `slice = torch.max(G,dim = 1)`. At each coordinate `[a,b]` of this slice, a 1 indicates that node `a` is connected by edge `b` to some other node (we don't care which).

```
slice = torch.max(G,dim = 1)                                     # dimension [n,e]
```

We're well on our way to the solution, but we need an expression that tells us whether `a` is connected to edge `b` and another edge `c`, for all edges `c`. We can map all combinations `b,c` by expanding `slice`, copying it and transposing it, and looking for intersections between the two.

```
expanded_dim = [slice.shape[0],slice.shape[1],slice.shape[1]]    # value [n,e,e]

# two copies of slice, expanded on different dimensions
expanded_slice = slice.unsqueeze(1).expand(expanded_dim)         # dimension [n,e,e]
transpose_slice = slice.unsqueeze(2).expand(expanded_dim)        # dimension [n,e,e]

G = torch.bitwise_and(expanded_slice,transpose_slice).int()      # dimension [n,e,e]
```

`G[i',j',k']` now equals 1 iff node `i'` is connected by edge `j'` to some other node, AND  node `i'` is connected by edge `k'` to some other node. If `j' = k'` the value is 1 as long as one of the endpoints of that edge is `i'`.

Lastly, we reorder dimensions to get to your desired form.

```
G = torch.permute(G,(1,2,0))           # dimension [e,e,n]
```